# Next.js: How to cache initial data on the server (same for all users)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm learning Next.js and started building one of my first applications - https://www.codart.io/

If you visit the site, you'll notice a delay until the collections become available: The application makes an initial graphql request to retrieve a json file with a number of NFT collections, which takes a few seconds. This data needs to be available across different components, so I built a global context to store the data (I'm not sure this is the best approach):
https://github.com/bartomolina/codart/blob/main/app/components/collections-context.tsx

```
const ArtBlocksContext = createContext({
  aBCollections: [] as IABCollection[],
  cACollections: [] as ICACollection[],
  fetchCACollections: () => {},
});

export const useArtBlocks = () => useContext(ArtBlocksContext);

export const ArtblocksProvider = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => {

...

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCACollections();
    execute(ArtblocksCollectionsDocument, {}).then((result) => {
```

I wonder what would be the best way to cache this data (as the data doesn't change often, it could be cached at build time, or ideally, indicating an expiration date i.e. 24 hours). Note that the cache will be shared between all users.

I've been looking at some similar posts, and I got some ideas, although it seems there isn't a clear and simple way to do this:

- Using Redux - Seems an overkill for a small project like this.
- Use some custom caching libraries - I'd rather not use any external libraries.
- Use getStaticProps along with the Context API - It seems you can't getStaticProps within the _app.ts page, so you would need to call it in every page where the context is used?
- Use SWR and an API call - SWR will cache the data, but on a per-user basis? i.e. the first time a user visits the site, it will still take a few seconds to load.

Comment: I would recommend solution to use service like redis

Comment: Thanks, never used Redis before. I also saw it mentioned in one of the posts, but I thought that it was kind of complex to implement and a bit of an overkill for just storing this JSON data, but I'm looking at it now and it seems pretty straightforward.